# Parent project to include common maven dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss

I have reached a point where there are a few projects that include the same dependencies.
I want to create a parent project which only contains a pom file where the common dependencies will reside.

Is there any particular type of project I should choose in jBoss/Eclipse that will help me with this parent project creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making such construction, you usually have 2 choices: 
1) Using a common parent that defines these dependencies
2) Adding a Maven module of type "pom", that just lists the common dependencies

Integrating solution 1) is easy, just make a module a child of that project (can be a grandchild of course). Dependencies will be inherited.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-company-parent-having-common-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

Integrating solution 2) is easy too. Just add a dependency on the pom module wherever it is needed, for instance:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>mycompany-module-declaring-bunch-of-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Depending on your project, you'll have to see if solution 1) or 2) suits better.
I recently used a construction like solution 2) when using a JBoss EAP 6 sample: https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/6.3.x-develop/helloworld-jms. They created some poms projects to aggregate dependencies that should be used together, such as all dependencies needed for a JMS client.